# Filtering both columns of an array with different limits and keeping only rows that meet both

Tags: matlab, concatenation, filtering

I am attempting to combine 2 column matrices in Matlab into one; example (Two 20x1 matrices into one 20x2):

```
a = randn(1,20)';
b = randn(1,20)';

c = [a,b];
```

My question is, how can I filter out each column so that, for example, I can filter out any values within column a of certain values (say `a(i)>0.8`) and filter out any values of column b with other values (say `b(i)<0.5`) and keep ONLY the rows in which both criteria are met?

In other words, I only want to keep the rows that meet both conditions `a(i)>0.8` & `b(i)<0.5`.
It should be fairly simple but I can't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = rand(1,20)';
b = rand(1,20)';
```

create a mask analyzing both vectors:

```
mask = a > 0.8 & b < 0.5
```

and then concatenate:

```
c = [a,b];
c = c(mask,:)
```

returns for example:

```
c =

    0.9421    0.3685
    0.8212    0.4868
```

---

or do it after concatenating:

```
c = [a,b];
d = c( c(:,1) > 0.8 & c(:,2) < 0.5 , : )
```